# Making a setup project which runs on LAN based connected PCs

Tags: c#, installation, inno-setup, setup-project, setup-deployment

**how can we run our c# form application on LAN based Connect PC?**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - do you want help writing a setup project, or help copying a database around? Either way, please post what code you have and tell us what isn't working with it.

Comment: i made a application(setup file also) for my office use,but now i want this application run on LAN based connect PC,

Comment: in this application,only server user(from LAN) can edit/update or change any DATA,and other connected PC users also get this updated DATA..

Comment: How is this question related to Inno Setup ?

Comment: @TLama Because of a making setup,read first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to mirroring your database across the LAN, if so, I suggest that you should try to make a central database and connect to it from your client by LAN connection,  any change to the database now can be read instantly from other machine.

Or, notify clients each time a record is changed on server.

Comment: hey dear,i walk through your suggesion and i found my solution thanks,now is it possible to  add question tag in setup which ask user to set database link,because whenever user change the database address its giving an error,can you help me in this??